ElectronJs require is not defined
I am trying to make an video recording software following tutorial https://youtu.be/3yqDxhR2XxE?si=vL0Se4LtEw0nkzkR
<!--index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>


  
  <script defer src="./renderer.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

// index.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('node:path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration:true,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.

const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron')

async function getVideoSources() {
    const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
        types: ['window', 'screen']
    })

    console.log(inputSources);
}
getVideoSources()

// the error i am getting on console

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at renderer.js:1:29

why the require is not defined, i also switched the renderer.js code into preload.js  then i am getting this error.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSources')
    at getVideoSources (VM116 C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\my-projects\software\my-app\src\preload.js:4:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM116 C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\my-projects\software\my-app\src\preload.js:10:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (VM116 C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\my-projects\software\my-app\src\preload.js:11:3)
    at Module._compile (VM56 loader:1484:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (VM56 loader:1564:10)
    at Module.load (VM56 loader:1295:32)
    at Module._load (VM56 loader:1111:12)
    at c._load (VM69 node_init:2:16955)
    at s._load (VM112 renderer_init:2:30981)
    at VM112 renderer_init:2:33050

can anyone help, why there is getSources is undefined i did not understand it, its my first time on electron.

renderer.js is evaluated in the browser and the browser doesn't understand require.

so what should i do, in previous version of electron there isn't any issue like this.

This was always an issue. You can't use require in the browser. You have to load the values in a Node.js script and pass it to the browser. The tutorial explains is: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-prerequisites
